# Generating a single geohash for a bounding box in python

Tags: python, polygon, extents, shapely, geohash

the following code generates bounding box for the coordinates that are given in the input but currently it generates geohashes for all the 4 coordinates of the polygon. i want to be able to generate a single hash for the bounding box that has been created from the coordinates. The outpus below show `pts` as 4 coordinates and `box` as the bounding box while `set` is the hashes generted from coordintes in `pts`.
i am using this geohash library  https://github.com/hkwi/python-geohash/wiki/GeohashReference

```
def bbox_geohashes_shapely(bbox_pts, accuracy=5):
 import geohash
        import shapely
        from shapely.geometry import Point

        unchecked = set()
        inside = set()
        outside = set()
        box=list()
        bbox = shapely.geometry.Polygon(bbox_pts)
        bbox = bbox.bounds
        print(bbox)
        for b in bbox:
            box.append(b)

        print (box,"box")
        print (bbox_pts,"pts")
        for pt in bbox_pts:
            tst_gh = geohash.encode(pt[0], pt[1], accuracy)
            unchecked.add(tst_gh)
        print(unchecked)
a=bbox_geohashes_shapely([(52.001158,7.572327),(52.002215,7.606909),(51.906366,7.692406),(51.901071,7.543488)],6)
```

**output**

```
(51.901071, 7.543488, 52.002215, 7.692406)
([51.901071, 7.543488, 52.002215, 7.692406], 'box')
([(52.001158, 7.572327), (52.002215, 7.606909), (51.906366, 7.692406), (51.901071, 7.543488)], 'pts')
set(['u1jru6', 'u1jrv4', 'u1jrr1', 'u1jr78'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old post but having an answer here would have saved me a little time.
For some reason I couldn't get the python library GeoHash to import so I grabbed the bit of code I needed from it

```
__base32 = '0123456789bcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz'
__decodemap = { }
def geohash(latitude, longitude, precision=12):
    """
    Encode a position given in float arguments latitude, longitude to
    a geohash which will have the character count precision.
    """
    lat_interval, lon_interval = (-90.0, 90.0), (-180.0, 180.0)
    geohash = []
    bits = [ 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 ]
    bit = 0
    ch = 0
    even = True
    while len(geohash) < precision:
        if even:
            mid = (lon_interval[0] + lon_interval[1]) / 2
            if longitude > mid:
                ch |= bits[bit]
                lon_interval = (mid, lon_interval[1])
            else:
                lon_interval = (lon_interval[0], mid)
        else:
            mid = (lat_interval[0] + lat_interval[1]) / 2
            if latitude > mid:
                ch |= bits[bit]
                lat_interval = (mid, lat_interval[1])
            else:
                lat_interval = (lat_interval[0], mid)
        even = not even
        if bit < 4:
            bit += 1
        else:
            geohash += __base32[ch]
            bit = 0
            ch = 0
    return ''.join(geohash)
```

I slimmed down your method a bit to get just the result.  I wanted a list of unique geohashes.

```
def getbboxhash(bbox_pts, accuracy=5):
    unchecked = []
    for pt in bbox_pts:
        tst_gh = geohash(pt[0], pt[1], accuracy)
        unchecked.append(tst_gh)
    return(unchecked)

print(getbboxhash([(52.001158,7.572327),(52.002215,7.606909),(51.906366,7.692406),(51.901071,7.543488)],8))
```

> ['u1jru6d0', 'u1jrv4en', 'u1jrr132', 'u1jr78m1']

Now that we have that we can determine a single hash that encompasses the entire bounding box as you asked for or dig a little bit deeper.

```
commonhash = []
different = []
for a in range(len(allhash[0])):
    blah =([x[a] for x in allhash])
    if len(set(blah))==1:
        commonhash.append(blah[0])
    else:
        different.append(blah)
        break
        
print('Common hash:',''.join(commonhash))
difflist = list(set(*different))
print('Different hash:',difflist)
newunique = []
for b in range(len(commonhash)):
    newunique.append(''.join(commonhash)+difflist[b])
print(newunique)
```

> Common hash: cb
>
> Different hash: ['4', '6']
>
> ['cb4', 'cb6']